# Pythonic way of creating a list of list of floats from text file

Tags: python, list, for-loop, map-function

I am reading from a csv_reader, line by line and trying to convert the list of strings of floats on the same line. Currently, I have:

```
list([float(i) for i in map(list, csv_reader)])
```

This clearly does not work. How would I achieve what I want? I want this all to be on a single line too.

Would I require two `map` functions? Maybe two Pythonic `for` loops?

The function that I am dealing with is:

```
def csv_input(filename):

    print(f'Currently reading the annotations from {filename}')

    try:
        csv_input_file = open(filename, 'rt')
    except FileNotFoundError:
        program_help()
        print("[Error] Input File not found")

    csv_reader = csv.reader(csv_input_file, delimiter=',')
    unfiltered_annots = list(float(i) for i in map(list, csv_reader))
    csv_input_file.close()

    return unfiltered_annots
```

My CSV file looks like this:

```
11, 11, 24, 24, 0.75
10, 11, 20, 20, 0.8
11, 9, 24, 24, 0.7
40, 42, 20, 20, 0.6
```

And the error I am getting is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "maximal_supression.py", line 124, in test_google_doc_example
    unfiltered_annots = csv_input('example_input.csv')
  File "maximal_supression.py", line 34, in csv_input
    unfiltered_annots = list(float(i) for i in map(list, csv_reader))
  File "maximal_supression.py", line 34, in <genexpr>
    unfiltered_annots = list(float(i) for i in map(list, csv_reader))
TypeError: float() argument must be a string or a number, not 'list'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to convert list to float. If you want to convert elements of list to floats, you should additionally iterate through your lists inside your list comprehension:

`unfiltered_annots = list([[float(i) for i in l] for l in map(list, csv_reader)])`

In my slightly converted code (for simplicity):

```
import csv

csv_input_file = open('a.csv', 'rt')
csv_reader = csv.reader(csv_input_file, delimiter=',')
unfiltered_annots = list([[float(i) for i in l] for l in map(list, csv_reader)])
csv_input_file.close()
unfiltered_annots
```

It returns the list of lists:

> ```
> [[11.0, 11.0, 24.0, 24.0, 0.75],
>  [10.0, 11.0, 20.0, 20.0, 0.8],
>  [11.0, 9.0, 24.0, 24.0, 0.7],
>  [40.0, 42.0, 20.0, 20.0, 0.6]]
> ```

---

P.S. As *@meowgoesthedog* mentioned, `csv_reader` returns lists so you don't need to map a list to csv_reader:

`unfiltered_annots = [list(map(float, l)) for l in csv_reader]`

Comment: `map(list, csv_reader)` is redundant because CSV readers yield rows as lists anyway

Comment: @meowgoesthedog why is it inefficient?

Comment: Can be reduced to `[[float(i) for i in l] for l in csv_reader]` or `[list(map(float, l)) for l in csv_reader]`

Comment: I think I like `[list(map(float, l) for l in csv_reader]` the most. Why don't you answer my question with that?

Comment: `File "maximal_supression.py", line 34
    unfiltered_annots = [list(map(float, l) for l in csv_reader]
                                                               ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax`

Comment: I added it to `P.S.` section to show that it is @meowgoesthedog 's idea. I think it is not fair to write another's code without any mention of that user.

Comment: @SharanDuggiral oops there was a missing parenthesis (`list(map(float, l)) # here`). You should learn to spot simple typos as it is a basic debugging skill.

Comment: @meowgoesthedog I did spot it! vurmux had the corrected version in his answer. Just wanted to point out that your code wasn't working. Thanks either way.